# Поворот врага на Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня есть ИИ врага. Враг держит в руках оружие и ходит туда-сюда, но, когда он начинает стрелять в игрока, он не может повернутьса и всё время в первом положении. Помогите его перевернуть в нужный момент.
Вот Код:
C#

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class IIEnemy : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed_enemy;
    public float stopping_distanse;

    public int positon_of_patrol;

    public Transform point;
    private Transform player;
    public Transform firePoint;
    public GameObject bulet;

    private bool moving_right;
    private bool chiil = false;
    private bool angry = false;
    private bool go_back = false;

    private float TimeBtwShotr;
    public float startTimebtw;

    private void Start()
    {
        player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").transform;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        // Если дистанцыя от игрока до точки меньше чем дистанцыя патруля
        if (Vector2.Distance(transform.position, point.position) < positon_of_patrol && angry == false)
        {
            chiil = true;
        }

        if (Vector2.Distance(transform.position, player.position) < stopping_distanse)
        {
            angry = true;
            chiil = false;
            go_back = false;
            Shoot();
        }
        if (Vector2.Distance(transform.position, player.position) > stopping_distanse)
        {
            go_back = true;
            angry = false;
        }

        if (chiil == true)
        {
            Chill();
        }
        else if (angry == true)
        {
            Angry();
        }
        else if (go_back == true)
        {
            GoBack();
        }

    }

    void Chill()
    {
        if (transform.position.x > point.position.x + positon_of_patrol)
        {
            moving_right = false;
        }
        else if(transform.position.x < point.position.x - positon_of_patrol)
        {
            moving_right = true;
        }

        if (moving_right)
        {
            transform.position = new Vector2(transform.position.x + speed_enemy * Time.deltaTime,transform.position.y);
        }
        else
        {
            transform.position = new Vector2(transform.position.x - speed_enemy * Time.deltaTime, transform.position.y);
        }
    }

    void Angry()
    {
        // двигатса к игроку
        transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position,player.position,speed_enemy * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    void GoBack()
    {
        transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, point.position, speed_enemy * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    private void Shoot()
    {
        if (TimeBtwShotr <= 0)
        {
            Instantiate(bulet, firePoint.position, firePoint.rotation);
            TimeBtwShotr = startTimebtw;
        }
        else
        {
            TimeBtwShotr -= Time.deltaTime;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

[DisallowMultipleComponent]
[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody2D))] // делает компонент обязательным

public class IIEnemy : MonoBehaviour
{
    public enum EnemyState { Chiil, Angry, GoBack }
    // public полей быть не должно
    [SerializeField] private float _moveSpeed = 1; // speed_enemy? какой смысл писать в имени enemy в классе enemy
    [SerializeField] private float _attackTime = 1;
    [SerializeField] private float _angryDistanse = 3; // _stoppingDistanse? явно не остановка
    [SerializeField] private float _patrolRange = 3; // positon_of_patrol не понятное имя в контексте того что это int, и почему это int?
    [SerializeField] private Transform _chillPoint; // point чего?
    [Space]
    [SerializeField] private Transform _firePoint;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject _buletTemplate;

    private Transform _transform;
    private Rigidbody2D _body; // вообщето движение делается через тело, незабудь добавить collider врагу и земле
    private Transform _player;
    private EnemyState _state; // удобнее ведь в место хреналиона bool, иметь что-то одно
    private float _patrolVector;
    private IEnumerator _attackCoroutine;

    private void Start ()
    {
        _transform = transform;
        _player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").transform;
        _body = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        _patrolVector = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, 2) == 0 ? 1 : -1;
        SetState(EnemyState.Chiil);
    }

    private void Update ()
    {
        switch (_state)
        {
            case EnemyState.Chiil: UpdateChill(); break;
            case EnemyState.Angry: UpdateAngry(); break;
            case EnemyState.GoBack: UpdateGoBack(); break;
        }
    }

    private void SetState (EnemyState state)
    {
        _state = state;
        if (_state == EnemyState.Angry)
        {
            // поскольку атака не постоянна, то делается с помощью корутины
            _attackCoroutine = AttackCoroutine();
            StartCoroutine(_attackCoroutine);
        }
        else if (_attackCoroutine != null)
        {
            StopCoroutine(_attackCoroutine);
        }
    }

    private void UpdateChill ()
    {
        if (_patrolVector > 0 && transform.position.x > _chillPoint.position.x+_patrolRange)
            _patrolVector = -1;
        else if (_patrolVector < 0 && transform.position.x < _chillPoint.position.x-_patrolRange)
            _patrolVector = 1;

        SetMoveVector(_patrolVector);
        if (PlayerIsClose() == true)
            SetState(EnemyState.Angry);
    }

    private void UpdateAngry ()
    {
        MoveTo(_player.position.x);
        if (PlayerIsClose() == false)
            SetState(EnemyState.GoBack);
    }

    private void UpdateGoBack ()
    {
        MoveTo(_chillPoint.position.x);
        if (Vector2.Distance(_transform.position, _chillPoint.position) < _patrolRange)
            SetState(EnemyState.Chiil);
        if (PlayerIsClose() == true)
            SetState(EnemyState.Angry);
    }

    private void MoveTo (float x)
    {
        SetMoveVector(x > _transform.position.x ? 1 : -1);
    }

    private void StopMove ()
    {
        SetMoveVector(0);
    }

    private void SetMoveVector (float vector)
    {
        Vector3 Velocity = _body.velocity;
        Velocity.x = vector*_moveSpeed;
        _body.velocity = Velocity;
        if (vector != 0)
            _transform.localScale = new Vector3(vector > 0 ? 1 : -1, 1, 1); // поворачиваем в сторону движения
    }

    private bool PlayerIsClose ()
    {
        return Vector2.Distance(_transform.position, _player.position) < _angryDistanse;
    }

    private IEnumerator AttackCoroutine ()
    {
        float Timer = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            Timer += Time.deltaTime;
            if (Timer >= _attackTime)
            {
                Shoot();
                Timer -= _attackTime;
            }
            yield return null; // задержка до следующего фрейма
        }
    }

    private void Shoot ()
    {
        Instantiate(_buletTemplate, _firePoint.position, _firePoint.rotation);
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо тебе большое

Comment: @саша чтобы принять ответ, надо поставить зеленую галочку слева от ответа

Comment: @саша, в этом коде могут быть ошибки. Если что задавай вопросы. Человеку который пишет код сам, тут с удовольствием отвечают.